# Link CSS to HTML string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create a HTML string within Javascript and wanted to link my css file into it but it does not seem to work.

```
const str =
    '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
    '<head>' +
        '<meta charset="UTF-8">' +
        '<title>' + title + '</title>' +
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">' +
    '</head>' +
    '<body>' +
        '<h1>' +  title + '</h1>' +
        'Total number of entries is: ' + number + '</br>' + imageString +
    '</body>' +
    '</html>';
```

Currently if I run the code above, it does a GET and tries going to /style.css within my web browser and does not look for the file within my directory.

Would appreciate any assistance, thank you very much! :)

EDIT: Currently if I try opening up the style.css file within my browser it links to 127.0.0.1:3000/style.css instead of the local style.css file. Does anyone know any method of changing this?

Comment: Open page source on your browser and click on the style.css, does it open up? If it doesn't and shows 404, then your path is set wrongly.

Comment: I tried that but the style.css isn't opening as it links to http://127.0.0.1:3000/style.css instead of the local style.css file

Comment: @Deep where is your style file located? If you were to manually navigate to the correct style file how would the full URL look like?

Comment: maybe put more info on your folder structure?

Comment: use ```/style.css``` the html page will start looking from file where it is residing.

Comment: how does this JavaScript get delivered to the browser?

Comment: Was an issue with the path. Thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You did not give a proper relative path. The path should be relative to the file in which you load this HTML string.

Comment: Please add how to make the path relative to your answer. Do you mean by adding a `./` ? or `../`? If you could elaborate it i think this answer could help more people.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have my style.css file within the exact same folder as the javascript file. I may be incorrect but to me the path looks correct.

Comment: I think the path will be relative to your HTML file not with a javascript file. so please check again it may help you.

Comment: Currently the path seems to be going to 127.0.0.1:3000/style.css instead of my local style.css file. Would you by any chance know how to change this? Thank you

Comment: I think you have to define a static path first something like this:
 `STATIC_URL = '/static/';`
then:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{STATIC_URL}style.css">`

Comment: Can you tell me on which tech stack you working on?

Comment: Figured it out, was an issue with the path and also static files. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing **"style.css"** to **"./style.css"** I don't know if this will solve but it's worth a try.

Comment: Hi, I tried those out but currently the path seems to be going to 127.0.0.1:3000/style.css instead of my local style.css file. Would you by any chance know how to change this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1:3000 this is the address of your localhost along with port number.
So it is actually equivalent to localhost:3000

Answer (score -1):

> Hey there! I think that your code in not working properly because you have entered so many apostrophe in your code, and it looks similar to an array.  You should use backtick (`) instead of apostrophe.
> Here's a demo...

```
const str =
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> ${title} </title> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> ${title} </h1>
        Total number of entries is:  ${number} </br> ${imageString}
    </body>
    </html>`;
```

> And ${} is another way to add a variable into a string. Now, after running your code, make sure you are adding your variable with this code in .innerHTML, not elsewhere.
> I don't know, but you can try displaying your code in console.log() to test if the code is working properly.

Comment: Two things, the line break character is with a back slash, so `\n` instead of `/n` and with the templating string you don't really need to use the line break character since it will remember the line breaks from the code. In short, you can remove `/n` from your code snippet

Comment: Thanks for telling my mistake. I edited the answer. At least, I learnt something new...